# group permission not working

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, file-permissions, groups

I'm installing gitlab at my server but I got a permission problem:

I have two users, 'git' and 'gitlab', both are part of group 'git', the home dir of 'git' has the `drwxr-----` permissions. Therefore 'gitlab' should be able to read it, but I got a permission denied when trying to change dir to 'git' home dir from 'gitlab' user.

Someone has any idea on that?

**/home/git and /home/git/repositories:**

```
523265 4 drwxr-----. 7 git  git  4096 Jul  3 06:15 git
523278 4 drwxrwx---. 7 git  git  4096 Jul  3 05:12 repositories
```

**'gitlab' groups:**

```
[gitlab@greenboxServer home]$ groups
gitlab git
[gitlab@greenboxServer home]$ id
uid=500(gitlab) gid=500(gitlab) groups=500(gitlab),488(git)
```

**'git' groups:**

```
sh-4.1$ groups
git
sh-4.1$ id
uid=495(git) gid=488(git) groups=488(git)
sh-4.1$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing directory requires the `x` permission on the directory.  The `r` permission allows you to `ls` the directory but not `cd` into it.

Try `chmod g+x /home/git`

This may seem slightly confusing but the `x` permission has been re-used for this purpose because it doesn't make sense to "execute" a directory.  Since that bit has no purpose for directories, it can be used to control access to change directory.

Comment: Thanks, settings g+x for /home/git also fixed permissions for /home/git/repositories.

Comment: I like to think of +x on directories as allowing you to execute a move into that directory.